# Merge array with multiple keys (php)

Tags: php, arrays

The array below is my current situation. Through a loop new data get's added.
I've tried 'array_merge_recursive' as well as this [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839697/php-find-same-keys-in-a-multidimensional-array-and-merge-the-findings/). But it doesn't seem to work or I'm using it wrong.

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [Customer] => Array (
                    [Weekend] => Array (
                            [2016] => Array (
                                    [01] => Array (
                                            [0] => Array (
                                                    [id] => 54
                                                    [startDate] => 01-01-2016
                                                    [endDate] => 31-12-2016
                                                    [price] => 0
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
    [1] => Array (
            [Customer] => Array (
                    [Weekend] => Array (
                            [2018] => Array (
                                    [01] => Array (
                                            [0] => Array (
                                                    [id] => 56
                                                    [startDate] => 01-01-2018
                                                    [endDate] => 31-12-2018
                                                    [price] => 0
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
    [2] => Array (
            [Customer] => Array (
                    [Weekend] => Array (
                            [2019] => Array (
                                    [01] => Array (
                                            [0] => Array (
                                                    [id] => 57
                                                    [startDate] => 01-01-2019
                                                    [endDate] => 31-12-2019
                                                    [price] => 0
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Desired situation is something like this:

```
Array (
                [Customer] => Array (
                    [Weekend] => Array (
                        [2016] => Array (
                            [01] => Array (
                                [0] => Array (
                                    [id] => 54
                                    [startDate] => 01-01-2016
                                    [endDate] => 31-12-2016
                                    [price] => 0
                                )
                            )
                        )
                        [2018] => Array (
                            [01] => Array (
                                [0] => Array (
                                    [id] => 56
                                    [startDate] => 01-01-2018
                                    [endDate] => 31-12-2018
                                    [price] => 0
                                )
                            )
                        )
                        [2019] => Array (
                            [01] => Array (
                                [0] => Array (
                                    [id] => 57
                                    [startDate] => 01-01-2019
                                    [endDate] => 31-12-2019
                                    [price] => 0
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
```

If any other information is required, please ask! new here

Comment: what if you do `array_values` on this code?

Comment: @Chris: Then you get the same array back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty sure this will work:

```
$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive', $array);
```

Comment: Much easier than mine hehe.

Comment: In the original array I used the ID from 'Customer' and 'Client' as keys, changed it for SO to make it more clear. that's why the 'array_merge_recursive' didn't work before. But using the name as key it works! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
$new_arr = [];
$arr = // Your current array;

foreach ($arr as $customer)
{
    foreach ($customer['Weekend'] as $year => $z)
    {
        foreach($z as $month => $y)
        {
            foreach($y as $entry)
            {
                Store($year, $month, $entry, $new_arr);
            }
        }
    }

}

function Store($year, $month, $entry, & $new_arr)
{
    if ( ! isset($new_arr['customer'][$year]))
    {
        $new_arr['customer'][$year] = array();
    }
    if ( ! isset($new_arr['customer'][$year][$month]))
    {
        $new_arr['customer'][$year][$month] = array();
    }
    $new_arr['customer'][$year][$month][] = $entry;
}
```